# Liquibase: runOnChange + rollback

Tags: liquibase

According to Liquibase docs stored procs/triggers etc should be stored separately in a single copy and added to changeset with runOnChange to update them for each change. But what is a recommended way to rollback to the previous change? The only idea that I have is to copy them to a separate folder for each release and add apply operation of this version as a rollback (for example, have sql\procs\current for last version all added to changelog as apply and sql\procs\1.0.0 is a copy of sql\procs\current when we started new 1.0.0 release). Are there any best practices for it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We keep single copy of replaceable objects (procs/triggers/views etc)
and use version control system (VCS) - git in our case.

When you want to rollback to previous version, just revert to relevant commit in VCS and run liquibase update.

[Tutorial using Oracle](https://web.archive.org/web/20200421092340/http://www.liquibase.org/tutorial-using-oracle) - we are working by this tutorial for two years.

Comment: Thanks, Albert. Looks like it is one of the options.